# Plural und Singularform des Wortes "Wahl"

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

Ist Singular- und Pluralform des Wortes "Wahl" im Sinne der politischen Abstimmung  gebräuchlich? Oder ist in diesem Sinne nur die Pluralform korrekt? (Die Zweifel kommen aus meiner Muttersprache.)

Comment: Sofern es nur um _eine_ geht, ist es eine _Wahl_, aktuell zum Beispiel die Bundestagswahl. Siehe auch hier: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahl

Comment: Gehört deine Muttersprache zu den slavischen? Von dort kenne ich die Verwendung standardmäßig im Plural, auch wenn es sich um - wie man im Deutschen sagen würde - eine konkrete, einzelne Wahl(prozedur) handelt.

Comment: Ja, meine Muttersprache ist Polnisch. Bei uns Singular würde etwas wie "choice" bedeuten und nicht die "politische Wahlen". Wie soll ich dann den folgenden Satz interpretieren: "Am 24. März 2006 hat der Europäische Rat als Reaktion auf die Präsidentschaftswahlen in Belarus vom 19. März 2006 (...)  beschlossen, dass..."? Geht es hier auch nicht um _eine_ Wahl?

Answer (score 6):

> Jetzt hat er wieder die Qual der Wahl.
>
> Würden Wahlen etwas ändern, wären sie verboten!

*Die Wahl* ist ein gewöhnliches Nomen. Mit dem Plural meint man mehrere Wahlvorgänge.

---

Es gibt außerdem noch das verwandte Nomen *die Auswahl*:

> Bei dieser Wahl ist die Auswahl riesig und bescheiden zugleich.

Mit der *Auswahl* ist bereits in der Einzahl die Menge der Optionen gemeint. Auch wenn man zwei Gruppen von Optionsmengen vergleicht, wird die Einzahl verwendet:

> Die beiden Läden haben eine unterschiedliche Auswahl.

Der Plural ist meist nicht sinnvoll einsetzbar, außer im übertragenen Sinn:

> Die Auswahlen Englands und Deutschlands treffen aufeinander.

Gemeint sind hier Sportmannschaften; *Nur die Besten des Landes!*